# While streaming video through live555 upon changing encoder resolution by 1 or 2 pixels the decoder not changes the resolution until refreshed

Tags: h.264, resolution, rtsp, ip-camera, live555

I am working on an IP camera. I know that H.264 encoder requires video resolution in multiple of 2 to work. Whenever I set a resolution on encoder lets say 1280x720 while live streaming is going on the decoder dynamically displays me the updated value. The problem here is that when I try to set the width just one scale lower say 1276x720 then it is correctly set on encoder but the decoder does not displays the change is width until I refresh the webpage or in case of vlc until I stop and start the streaming again. I have verified the same on vlc also. If I set to lower resolution by more than just few pixels like 1272x720 then both my webbrowser and vlc updates the value dynamically.
I have also cross verified it with H.265 codec but it doesn't seem to be the problem on that.

Anyone has the idea what might be the reason for that because the values are updated even though only the stream has been stopped and start again and nothing changes in between.

Answer (score 0):

H.264 needs 16x16 alignment. For example 1920 x 1080 is actually encoded as 1920 x 1088.
The pixel accurate resolution is achieved by using the the frame_crop_* values in the sequence parameter set. Now - I can only guess that the decoder (your website or VLC) doesn't dynamically evaluate the frame_crop_* values.